# Foreign Key Entity Framework 6 getting null inserted in dependent table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to use the Primary Key Id from AspNetUsers for my Contractor table and it is giving me an error saying "Cannot insert NULL value into Column ID". The error happens when I try to create a Contractor after I have registered a user and they appear in AspNetUsers.

```
  public class Contractor
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; } 



 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public virtual Contractor Contractor { get; set; }
```

**EDIT**

The Contractor is the Base Class for Musician.
Code for creation of Musician from Controller

```
     public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FirstName,LastName,ZipCode,Phone,PrimaryInstrument,PrimaryGenre,NextDateAvailable,WebsiteLink, YouTubeLink,SoundCloudLink, ReverbNationLink,YearsOfExperience,Description")] Musician musician, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                string imageFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
                image.SaveAs(imageFilePath + image.FileName);

                musician.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                musician.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                musician.ImageName = image.FileName;

            }


            musician.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;

            db.Musicians.Add(musician);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }

        return View(musician);
    }
```

The Musician class:

```
  public class Musician : Contractor
{
    public string PrimaryInstrument { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryGenre { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteLink { get; set; }
    public string YouTubeLink { get; set; }
    public string SoundCloudLink { get; set; }
    public string  ReverbNationLink { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the code for creating Contractor?

Comment: Is `ApplicationUser` in a one-to-one relationship with `Contractor`?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker please select my answer as correct or write an Answer for your own question so the topic is closed. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino I am not the OP , so i cannot select your answer.
Also you shouldn't ask people to make your answer as the correct one.
and topics aren't just closed. there will always be a conversation or an update to the solution

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker, oops. I just said he should select some answer because he found a solution to his problem, as you can see on the conversation in my answer. Sorry for mistaking you for the OP, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize I can use User.Identity.GetUserId() for the Id value and save that to my model for the database. It solved the foreign key issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this code on the `OnModelCreating` event of your `context` class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasOptional<Contractor>(user => user.Contractor)
    .WithRequired(cont => cont.ApplicationUser)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This is for "one-to-one relationship" between `ApplicationUser` and `Contractor` (with `ApplicationUser` **not** requiring a `Contractor`).

If you want the `Contractor` to be **required** for every user, just change `HasOptional` for `HasRequired`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice. I used musician.ID = User.Identity.GetUserId(); in my controller when saving. I am getting the AspNetUser primary key saved to the Contractor id to connect them. Please let me know if there may be an issue with that. Thanks

Comment: I believe you should be fine. But make sure you won't have problems by deleting any of the relationship members.